# Help Installing Perl Module XML::Parser using CPAN

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm trying to install the XML::Parser perl module using CPAN and can't get it to work. Below is the output that is being displayed by CPAN which appears to indicate that Expat is the issue. I've verified that the latest version of Expat is installed on the system.

Geting this installed is critical for us and I'm at a loss as to what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Expat verification

```
# yum install expat-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * rpmforge: fr2.rpmfind.net
amzn                                                                                                                                                             | 2.1 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
Package expat-devel-1.95.8-8.3.8.amzn1.i386 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

XML::Parser Install

```
cpan[1]> install XML::Parser
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.21)
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 03 May 2011 00:28:04 GMT
Running install for module 'XML::Parser'
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v0.72)
Running make for C/CH/CHORNY/XML-Parser-2.40.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.48)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.03)
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/CH/CHORNY/XML-Parser-2.40.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /root/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.68)
XML-Parser-2.40
XML-Parser-2.40/Changes
XML-Parser-2.40/Makefile.PL
XML-Parser-2.40/MANIFEST
XML-Parser-2.40/META.yml
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser.pm
XML-Parser-2.40/README
XML-Parser-2.40/Expat
XML-Parser-2.40/Expat/encoding.h
XML-Parser-2.40/Expat/Expat.pm
XML-Parser-2.40/Expat/Expat.xs
XML-Parser-2.40/Expat/Makefile.PL
XML-Parser-2.40/Expat/typemap
XML-Parser-2.40/inc
XML-Parser-2.40/inc/Devel
XML-Parser-2.40/inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/LWPExternEnt.pl
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/big5.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/euc-kr.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/ibm866.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-2.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-3.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-4.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-5.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-7.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-8.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-9.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/Japanese_Encodings.msg
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/koi8-r.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/README
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/windows-1250.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/windows-1251.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/windows-1252.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/windows-1255.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/x-euc-jp-jisx0221.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/x-euc-jp-unicode.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/x-sjis-cp932.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/x-sjis-jdk117.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/x-sjis-jisx0221.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Encodings/x-sjis-unicode.enc
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Style
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Style/Debug.pm
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Style/Objects.pm
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Style/Stream.pm
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Style/Subs.pm
XML-Parser-2.40/Parser/Style/Tree.pm
XML-Parser-2.40/samples
XML-Parser-2.40/samples/canonical
XML-Parser-2.40/samples/canontst.xml
XML-Parser-2.40/samples/ctest.dtd
XML-Parser-2.40/samples/REC-xml-19980210.xml
XML-Parser-2.40/samples/xmlcomments
XML-Parser-2.40/samples/xmlfilter
XML-Parser-2.40/samples/xmlstats
XML-Parser-2.40/t
XML-Parser-2.40/t/astress.t
XML-Parser-2.40/t/cdata.t
XML-Parser-2.40/t/decl.t
XML-Parser-2.40/t/defaulted.t
XML-Parser-2.40/t/encoding.t
XML-Parser-2.40/t/ext.ent
XML-Parser-2.40/t/ext2.ent
XML-Parser-2.40/t/external_ent.t
XML-Parser-2.40/t/file.t
XML-Parser-2.40/t/finish.t
XML-Parser-2.40/t/foo.dtd
XML-Parser-2.40/t/namespaces.t
XML-Parser-2.40/t/parament.t
XML-Parser-2.40/t/partial.t
XML-Parser-2.40/t/skip.t
XML-Parser-2.40/t/stream.t
XML-Parser-2.40/t/styles.t
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)

  CPAN.pm: Going to build C/CH/CHORNY/XML-Parser-2.40.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for XML::Parser::Expat
Writing Makefile for XML::Parser
cp Parser/Encodings/x-sjis-cp932.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/x-sjis-cp932.enc
cp Parser/Encodings/koi8-r.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/koi8-r.enc
cp Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-7.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-7.enc
cp Parser/Encodings/ibm866.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/ibm866.enc
cp Parser/Style/Tree.pm blib/lib/XML/Parser/Style/Tree.pm
cp Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-9.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-9.enc
cp Parser/Encodings/x-euc-jp-unicode.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/x-euc-jp-unicode.enc
cp Parser/Encodings/README blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/README
cp Parser/Encodings/euc-kr.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/euc-kr.enc
cp Parser/Encodings/windows-1250.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/windows-1250.enc
cp Parser/Encodings/windows-1252.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/windows-1252.enc
cp Parser/Encodings/big5.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/big5.enc
cp Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-3.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-3.enc
cp Parser/Encodings/Japanese_Encodings.msg blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/Japanese_Encodings.msg
cp Parser/Encodings/windows-1255.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/windows-1255.enc
cp Parser/Encodings/x-euc-jp-jisx0221.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/x-euc-jp-jisx0221.enc
cp Parser/Style/Subs.pm blib/lib/XML/Parser/Style/Subs.pm
cp Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-4.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-4.enc
cp Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-8.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-8.enc
cp Parser/Encodings/x-sjis-jdk117.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/x-sjis-jdk117.enc
cp Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-2.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-2.enc
cp Parser/Encodings/x-sjis-unicode.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/x-sjis-unicode.enc
cp Parser/LWPExternEnt.pl blib/lib/XML/Parser/LWPExternEnt.pl
cp Parser/Style/Objects.pm blib/lib/XML/Parser/Style/Objects.pm
cp Parser.pm blib/lib/XML/Parser.pm
cp Parser/Style/Debug.pm blib/lib/XML/Parser/Style/Debug.pm
cp Parser/Encodings/windows-1251.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/windows-1251.enc
cp Parser/Encodings/x-sjis-jisx0221.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/x-sjis-jisx0221.enc
cp Parser/Style/Stream.pm blib/lib/XML/Parser/Style/Stream.pm
cp Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-5.enc blib/lib/XML/Parser/Encodings/iso-8859-5.enc
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/.cpan/build/XML-Parser-2.40-tJglwK/Expat'
cp Expat.pm ../blib/lib/XML/Parser/Expat.pm
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `ExtUtils/xsubpp', needed by `Expat.c'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/.cpan/build/XML-Parser-2.40-tJglwK/Expat'
make: *** [subdirs] Error 2
  CHORNY/XML-Parser-2.40.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command:
CHORNY/XML-Parser-2.40.tar.gz                : make NO
```

Comment: Can you use the perl-XML-Parser package that is in the RHEL/CentOS repositories?

Answer (score 0):

The missing target, `xsubpp`, is part of core perl for modern perls, and the installation process should be able to find out where it is.  What version of perl do you have installed?  What happens when you try installing XML::Parser by hand (i.e. download the tarball, run `perl Makefile.PL && make`)?  It sounds as if the `perl Makefile.PL` step isn't able to find `xsubpp`.  You may want to install a newer version of `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`.

Comment: @justarobert - Perl v5.10.1, ExtUtils::MakeMaker is up-to-date (v6.56) according to CPAN. What would be causing perl not to be able to find xsubpp and what can we do to fix that? Really appreciate the help!

Comment: In `/root/.cpan/build/XML-Parser-2.40/Expat/Makefile`, what is the value of XSUBPPDIR? Can you find `xsubpp` anywhere in your filesystem? I might expect it in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/lib/perl5/5.10.1/ExtUtils/xsubpp`.

Comment: XSUBPPDIR = ExtUtils

Comment: xsubpp appears to be installed in the following directory /usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils/xsubpp

Comment: You should then be able to change the value of `XSUBPPDIR` to `/usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils`, change directory to `/root/.cpan/build/XML-Parser-2.40`, and run `make; make test` (and, if all tests pass, `make install`). However, there is something more generally wrong if MakeMaker is failing to find the right value for `XSUBPPDIR`.

Comment: Didn't seem to work. Here is what I received when I tried to run make in the XML-Parser-2.40 directory:

make
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/.cpan/build/XML-Parser-2.40-mELUa4/Expat'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `ExtUtils/xsubpp', needed by `Expat.c'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/.cpan/build/XML-Parser-2.40-mELUa4/Expat'
make: *** [subdirs] Error 2

Comment: Did you modify `/root/.cpan/build/XML-Parser-2.40/Expat/Makefile`?

Comment: I did. I updated it to XSUBPPDIR = /usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils

Comment: Odd. Possibly you need to update `/root/.cpan/build/XML-Parser-2.40/Makefile` as well. Failing that, I suppose you could run `mkdir -p /root/.cpan/build/XML-Parser-2.40/Expat/ExtUtils; ln -s /usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils/xsubpp /root/.cpan/build/XML-Parser-2.40/Expat/ExtUtils`, but then it's really a hack.